# maximum value of a vector displays as 0

Tags: c++, function, vector

I enter a vector `A = {0,10}`.
Then I add `2` to each element that is less than the average and subtract `2` from each element that is more the average. After this operation, the new vector is `{2,8}` but when I try to print the maximum value of this vector, I get **`0`** for some reason.

```
int smallestRangeI(vector<int>& A, int K) {
        int sum = 0;
        int avg = accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), sum);
        avg = avg / A.size();
        for(int i = 0; i<A.size();i++)
        {
            if(A[i]<avg) A[i]=A[i]+K;
            else A[i]=A[i]-K;
        }
        return *max(A.begin(), A.end());
    }
int main() {
    vector<int> A = {0,10};
    int K = 2;
    cout<<smallestRangeI(A,K);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code statement by statement in a debugger to see what happens and what the results of all calculations are? Hint: It helps to put statements on different lines for this.

Comment: I recommend completing the question by adding the missing headers. It doesn't matter much in this case, but everything we have to change in order to get your example compiling is a chance for us to alter the behaviour and accidentally introduce another bug or accidentally fix the one you're hunting.

Comment: On a side note, your use of `sum` is wrong. It should look more like this instead: `int sum = accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0); int avg = sum / A.size();`

Comment: actually i did some changes to the code last second and couldn't keep track of sensible variable names lol. well what you are saying is absolutely correct haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::max` returns the larger of the 2 elements. You are passing it two iterators, the larger of which is `A.end()`, and then you're dereferencing that, which invokes undefined behavior.

It appears you are looking for `std::max_element` instead, which gives you an iterator to the largest value in `A` which you can then dereference:

```
return *max_element(A.begin(), A.end());
```

Note that you shouldn't dereference this iterator if there's any chance that `A` might be empty, since this will invoke undefined behavior as well. Also, if `A` is empty, this operation `avg / A.size()` results in a division by 0.

What this function does in the case that `A` is empty is up to you.

Comment: maybe add a check for the `end` iterator. All the rest of the function is fine with an empty vector (... well not really all of it)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Very good point, added to the answer, thanks.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Actually, the rest of the function looks ok to me. There's a mixed sign comparison in the loop, but that shouldn't break anything.

Comment: i first missed this one: `avg = avg / A.size();`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Oops, that was careless. Thanks a lot, added that as well.